# How can I get Blender to snap vert using grab command?

Tags: snapping

So I am taking a short course modeling house on Udemi. I noticed that when I use extrude command it is very easy to snap to another vert. However, at one point we need to subdivide (basically one vert missing) to help with making a wall. The teacher just grabs this vert, constrains it to x and snaps it in-line with another vert. 
My blender will not do that, even if I have the same snapping settings on as the teacher's Blender.
Blender seems not to notice the vert I want to snap to while grabbing, but if I extrude from another place it snaps to it with no problem.
Then I tried to move a door opening to have it in-line with another door, but it will not snap. If I extrude from a vert, it snaps where I want it to snap within second.
My settings are: Snap on, vertices, closest, and snap onto itself. 
Am I missing some settings or is this a bug?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the blender file you are having trouble with so we can have a look at it? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The site you asked me to upload to doesn't allow me to update my file. I drag my file to the box, check the "accept terms and conditions" give my link and press upload just to have an error saying "Please accept terms and conditions".

Comment: I have tried several times now, always get the same error. IF I accidentally uploaded the same file multiple times, I am sorry. The site here asks me to accept terms and conditions. I don't know where else I should accept but the box below the drag-n-drop box.

Comment: Just upload it somewhere, google drive is a good choice, I just linked that site because it is the most common site for blend files here.

Comment: I managed to add the file yesterday.
Then I got a "Suggested edit" which I have no idea how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have proportional editing on, press O, or the blue dot at the bottom of the viewport to turn it off (see circled in red) [image: screenshot]
You also might have forgotten to turn auto merge on (circled in blue), as you seem to have 4 vertices overlapping. To remove them, select everything (A) and use the Remove Doubles function (Press space and search up Remove Doubles).

Comment: This was too simple, thank you anyway for the time. I feel bit silly for this post now :/

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson Please accept it as the correct answer by clicking on the tick :)